# How to add a catchall address to opensmtpd without disrupting existing aliases

Tags: email, opensmtpd

I have a working OpenSMTPD configuration that I am happy with.

I do not have a virtuser file and I do not reference "domain_mail" or virtual anywhere in my config file, which is here:

```
table aliases file:/usr/local/etc/mail/aliases

filter check_dyndns phase connect match rdns regex { '.*\.dyn\..*', '.*\.dsl\..*' } \
    disconnect "550 no residential connections"

filter check_rdns phase connect match !rdns \
    disconnect "550 no rDNS"

filter check_fcrdns phase connect match !fcrdns \
    disconnect "550 no FCrDNS"

listen on 100.150.200.135 port 10028 tag DKIM
listen on 100.150.200.135 filter \
    { check_dyndns, check_rdns, check_fcrdns }
    listen on 100.150.200.135 port submission

    action "local_mail" mbox alias <aliases>
    action "relay_dkim" relay host smtp+notls://100.150.200.135:10027
    action "outbound" relay helo mail.example.com

    match tag DKIM for any action "outbound"
    match from any for domain "example.com" action "local_mail"
    match from any auth for any action "outbound"
    match for local action "local_mail"
    match for any action "relay_dkim"
```

Again, everything works great and I am happy - I *just want to add a catchall address* so that emails to nonexistent@example.com can be directed into a mailbox.

I thought this would be a five minute fix - just add a line like this:

```
@     catchall
```

... to my aliases file and be done.  BUT, opensmtpd does not allow something simple and convenient like that - you cannot use the '@' catchall in the aliases file even though that would be very simple and safe and help many use-cases.

Instead, it looks like I need to put the '@' rule in a virtusertable and add all of that complexity to my (nice and simple) opensmtpd conf file.

Two hours later I have not succeeded.

I don't understand how to make aliases and virtuals work together and I don't understand why I would rip out all of my working aliases and move them to virtuals but I also can't get the two of them to coexist nicely.

So the question is:

IF ALL I want out of virtual users is just that simple '@' catchall, is it possible to specify just that simple rule, by itself, *inside the opensmtpd config file* without adding in all of the virtual action/match logic and maintaining a second mapping table in addition to the aliases file I already have ?

Thank you.

Comment: I have to admit, I only use OpenSMTPD for sending and relaying, but I'm wondering what is the exact format you use in `aliases` and what error you receive with `@`? I'm pretty sure that should work.

Comment: It is my understanding - and I see it repeated elsewhere - that the @ catchall only applies when handling mail for virtual users.  I attempted a single '@' then a tab then a local user (following the pattern I use with all of my aliases) and it just gave me 550 Invalid recipient errors.

Comment: ... and just to add ... I am dying to know why the @ catchall is excluded from the alias file - what is the Very Important Reason that we can't just use '@' in aliases and avoid unnecessary complexity ?  It seems like a no-brainer ...